# If I create a temporary file and modify it very frequently, does this put a burden on the disk?

Tags: c#, temporary-files, system.io.file

I need to write a can change at any time stream to the file for others reading elsewhere, but if the disk is modified too frequently, this will definitely damage the disk.

It's said that Temporary file will use memory as possible without actually write into disk.

But I've found it "seems" still writing into disk.

Who can answer my confusion?

Comment: Hdd/Sdd has a *buffer cache* (several Megabytes) which has been specially desingned for this very purpose (caching *hot spots* - frequently modifiing data) https://superuser.com/questions/309613/do-solid-state-disks-ssds-have-a-buffer-cache

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This means that I don't need to worry too much about the file stream changing frequently will damage the disk?

Comment: @Dmitry that answers the question, I'd upvote it...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If I switch to use `Copy`, it will make some trouble, right?

Comment: Would you have any issues with file concurrency? If the file is being used frequently to write things, would you have problems with the file being locked?

Comment: @Flithor: no trouble, hot spot data (with high probability) will stay at the *buffer cache* (the chunk will be marked as beloning to *two* files)

Comment: @Cesar Bourdain Costa: on the *hardware* level - no; however, it may appear thet you'll have to design elaborated software

Comment: @CesarBourdainCosta file is really locked, if I close the stream the file will write to the disk...Sorry for my previous response

Comment: @DmitryBychenko hmmm...file was locked, other I can't open that file by other stream

Comment: @Flithor: yes it's a typical *software* (not *hardware*) problem. You may lock file partially (e.g. when appending the file you can put an exclusive lock on the last segment of the file) e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/locking-and-unlocking-byte-ranges-in-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern HDD / SDD has a *buffer cache* (with a typical size of several *Megabytes*) which has been *specially designed* for this very issue:
caching *hot spots*, frequently read and modified data. It's much *faster* to read/write data using memory than HDD; 
SDD has another problem: *limited number of writes* and thus we should avoid too frequent writes. In case of *power off*, a capacitor 
(or HDD disks rotation) provides enough energy to safely write down all the data from cache back to HDD/SDD.

In case of `Copy` hot *spot data* will (with a high probability) stay at cache.

Resume: please, don't re-invent the wheel, let hardware manufactors do their own work and solve the (very typical) issue for you.